# Having a issue regarding DataTables paggingType = "input"

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable, pagination

i'm using datatables and for pagination i've used paggingtype = "input" and also included its plugin cdn but unfortunately when i used this, it is automatically disabling the First Next Previous and Last pagination buttons and i needed them enabled so that i can use them alongwith input text field.. Any help will be a huge favor

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#categories').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "pagingType" : "input",
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : ajaxurl + "/ManageCategories/fetchCategories",
            "type" : "POST"
        }
    });
});
```

and here's my DataTable showing output:
[image]

thanks,
Ameer

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to my question i.e. whenever "paggingType" is used it will overwrite the default "paggingType" so in order to get a text input i can add it manually by inserting this javaScript:

```
$("div.toolbar").html('<div><input type="text" id="pageJump" placeholder="page"> 
<button id="jump" type="button">Go</button></div>');

$('#jump').click( function() {
table.page(parseInt($('#pageJump').val())-1).draw(false);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try `simple_numbers` and check

```
"pagingType": "simple_numbers"
```

---

```
simple_numbers: function ( page, pages ) {
    return [ 'previous', _numbers(page, pages), 'next' ];
},
```

> **`simple_numbers` - *'Previous'* and *'Next'* buttons, plus *page numbers***

[`pagingType` Datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType)